# trouble setting up cucumber to test without actually changing the file system

Tags: ruby, cucumber, aruba

I have been struggling for a while with this problem. I'm trying to test a ruby CLI that uses a lot of `fileutils` operations like making directories and copying files, etc. But when I'm writing tests, I need some way to test the functionality without touching and changing the actual filesystem. I am trying to use the `fakefs` gem but I am running into a error right away

```
When I successfully run `dotfiles init`                           # aruba-0.5.3/lib/aruba/cucumber.rb:71
      No such file or directory - No such file or directory - /tmp/aruba-out20130817-15800-ke8nou (Errno::ENOENT)
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tempfile.rb:146:in `open'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tempfile.rb:146:in `block in initialize'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tmpdir.rb:142:in `create'
      /Users/Brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tempfile.rb:136:in `initialize'
      features/dotfiles_repository.feature:8:in `When I successfully run `dotfiles init`'
```

So its not finding `/tmp/aruba` which is where cucumber aruba does all of its file operations according to the [readme](https://github.com/cucumber/aruba).
The tests run fine without `fakefs`, so I'm assuming its something with the setup.

Here is my `features/support/env.rb` file

```
require 'aruba/cucumber'
require 'fakefs/safe'

Before do
  FakeFS.activate!
end

After do
  FakeFS::FileSystem.clear
  FakeFS.deactivate!
end
```

Does anyone have any idea what I may be doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Even if its an idea that doesn't use fakefs, I would like to hear it. Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you find any good solutions for this?

Comment: Looks like it's better to put those activate! and other stuff right before/after we use the fake file system, not in Before/After hooks.